# Was the Chinese ship Da Cui Yun carrying materials for building WMD?

Tags: china, india, pakistan

- [Chinese ship carrying suspected cargo to Pakistan allowed to leave, equipment held back](https://theprint.in/defence/chinese-ship-carrying-suspected-cargo-to-pakistan-allowed-to-leave-equipment-held-back/369182/)
- [DRDO confirms Chinese ship India stopped was carrying nuclear-capable equipment to Pakistan](https://theprint.in/india/drdo-confirms-chinese-ship-india-stopped-was-carrying-nuclear-capable-equipment-to-pakistan/375184/)

The above article says that: India seized a Chinese ship that was carrying equipment that was supposed to be used to build nuclear weapons, and was destined for Pakistan.

> A team of DRDO scientists was sent in, and it came to the prima facie conclusion that the item was not a dryer but an autoclave — a pressure chamber to carry out various industrial and scientific processes.
>
> It has been certified as a “dual-use” item, which means it can be used for civilian and military purposes.
>
> If it is indeed proved that the ship had mis-declared a dual-use technology item, the government could invoke the Weapons of Mass Destruction and Their Delivery Systems (Prohibition of Unlawful Activities) Act, 2005.
>
> The owner of the ship and the captain could also be charged for violating the Special Chemicals, Organisms, Materials, Equipment and Technologies (SCOMET) export rules.
>
> [...]
>
> “The autoclave can be used for the manufacture of the motor of very long range missiles, with range upwards of 1,500 kilometres or even in the construction of a motor for the launch of satellites. Pakistan has the Shaheen II missile in the 1,500-2,000 kilometre range and the platform was tested last May,” said one of the officials, who asked not to be named.

Now, this story doesn't make any sense, and raises the following questions:

1. Pakistan already possesses nuclear weapons. That means they received these types of equipment before. So, how did China transport that equipment to Pakistan before?
2. Why would the Chinese government risk sending a civilian ship loaded with WMD-capable equipment without a military escort? Why didn't they send that equipment by a PLAN ship?
3. There is a border crossing between Pakistan and China. So, why didn't China deliver that equipment via military trucks?
4. Why didn't China send that equipment by Y-20 military cargo aircraft?
5. Why didn't Pakistan send one of its IL-78 military cargo planes to China?
6. why didn't China make any fuss about it? Why would they be so polite to India?

The above questions are all unanswered.

The miffing part about this is: if China knew of the military destination of the cargo for Pakistan, why did the ship dock in India?

Was the Chinese ship really carrying materials for building WMD, or was India just trying to embarrass China by making use of a half-truth (dual use of autoclaves)?

Comment: Just because they have nuclear weapons doesn't mean they have a lot of them or the tech to build more.

Comment: The autoclave in the photo looked huge. Maybe it doesn't fit on a plane? The UK [does](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1052560/uk-strategic-export-control-lists.pdf) consider some such feed autoclaves as dual-use, but I'm no expert.

Comment: Apparently, size is an issue because autoclaves can be used for polymerization of solid-fuel rocket boosters. http://www.s3l.be/usr/files/di/fi/2/2020-2021--05---Solid-rocker-motor-propulsion_2020929203.pdf So the bigger the thing, the larger rocket motors you can make, apparently. The process was used for the space shuttle too https://aerospaceamerica.aiaa.org/departments/better-booster-production/

Comment: The miffing part about this is: if China new of the military destination of the cargo for Pakistan, why did the ship dock in India?

Comment: Regarding your point 6, "fuss" is relative as both Pakistan FO and China MFA denied the item is for military use https://www.dawn.com/news/1539177 Frankly I'm not sure how this question can be answered since it looks like no international organizations or press outside India/Pakistan took interest in this dispute.